# Using op inputs when defining custom gradients in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to define a gradient method for my custom TF operation. Most of the solutions I have found online seem to based on a [gist](https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342) by [harpone](https://github.com/harpone). I'm reluctant to use that approach as it uses `py_func` which won't run on GPU. I found another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256517/how-to-register-a-custom-gradient-for-a-operation-composed-of-tf-operations) that uses `tf.identity()` that looks more elegant and I *think* will run on GPU. However, I have some problems accessing inputs of the ops in my custom gradient function. Here's my code:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient('MyCustomGradient')
def _custom_gradient(op, gradients):
    x = op.inputs[0]
    return(x)

def my_op(w):
    return tf.pow(w,3)


var_foo = tf.Variable(5, dtype=tf.float32)
bar = my_op(var_foo)


g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({'Identity': 'MyCustomGradient'}):
    bar = tf.identity(bar)
    g = tf.gradients(bar, var_foo)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(g))
```

I was expecting `_custom_gradient()` to return the input to the op (5 in this example) but instead it seems to return `op output x gradient`. My custom my_op will have non-differentiable operations like tf.sign and I'd like to define my custom gradient based on the inputs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think what's going on is that the custom gradient is attached to the `identity()` op and not the `my_op()` function as I had hoped.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your code:

Let's first do the forward pass:

`var_foo = 5`  -> `bar = 125`   ->  `tf.identity(bar) = 125`

Now let's backpropagate:

The gradient of `tf.identity(bar)` with respect to its argument `bar` equals (by your definition) to `bar`, that is, `125`. The gradient of `bar` with respect to `var_foo` equals 3 times the square of `var_foo` which is `75`. Multiply, and you get `9375`, which is indeed the output of your code.

`op.inputs[0]` contains the forward-pass value of the op. In this case, the forward pass of the `identity` op is `125`.

Comment: Thanks that makes total sense. I was hoping to define a custom gradient for the `my_op` function but instead I've defined it for tf.identity. I guess I have to fall back to py_func.